# qTip shows margin even when not set?

Tags: jquery, css, qtip

Why does qTip add a margin even when none is set for the tooltip?

Here's the qTip configuration I'm using:

```
$.fn.qtip.styles.mystyle = { 
               width: 200,
               background: '#b7d5f4',
               color: '#212121',
               textAlign: 'left',
               border: {
                  width: 1,
                  radius: 5,
                  color: '#b7d5f4'
               },
               tip: 'bottomLeft',
               name: 'dark'
            }

            $.each($(".tooltip"), function(i,val){
                var theContent = $(val).html();
                $(val).qtip({
                     content: theContent,
                     position: {
                              corner: {
                                 target: 'topRight',
                                 tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
                              }
                           },
                     style: 'mystyle'
             });
});
```

The content div's class styles looks like this:

```
.ttContent
{
    width:                  200px;
    margin-left:           -8px;
    margin-top:            -15px;
}
```

Why do I have to use negative margin to get proper margins here?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? and why you are suing non-breaking spaces? it's [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/Hne3h/4/) what you want?

Comment: @ifaur > Thanks! that looks grate, but the icon in the tooltip is still a bit far to the right. But is it Okay to use negative margin to handle this? If you place a answer on this question I will grant it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$.fn.qtip.styles.mystyle = {
    /*width: 200,*/
    background: '#b7d5f4',
    color: '#212121',
    textAlign: 'left',
    padding: 2,
    border: {
        width: 1,
        radius: 5,
        color: '#b7d5f4'
    },
    tip: 'bottomLeft',
    name: 'dark'
}

$.each($(".tooltip"), function(i, val) {

    var theContent = $(val).html();
    $(val).qtip({
        content: theContent,
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topRight',
                tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            }
        },
        style: 'mystyle'
    });
});
```

I've removed the non-breaking spaces, the qtip width (to expand to the content width) and applied a smaller padding.

A working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/Hne3h/5/).